# Kotlin MutableList initial capacity

Tags: kotlin, arraylist

I'm creating a list of values, in a context where it so happens that, though the values are being added one at a time, the eventual number is known in advance. This is in a function that will be called many times, so the faster it runs, the better.

In Java, I would use the ArrayList constructor that specifies an initial capacity, because in theory this makes it slightly faster because it avoids resizing.

In Kotlin, one normally uses mutableListOf(), but this does not allow an initial capacity; in theory this should result in slightly slower code.

Is the recommended/idiomatic Kotlin solution in this case:

1. Go ahead and use the ArrayList constructor; ArrayList is a perfectly valid MutableList.
2. Ignore the issue; the initial capacity never actually makes a measurable difference to speed.
3. Something else?

Comment: I would  use the ArrayList constructor. You're trying to use specific functionality to optimize in a certain way, so in that case it makes sense to use a concrete class rather than an interface. You can still assign it to a MutableList property.

Comment: I agree with Tenfour04 (and strongly disagree with the accepted answer).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Updated Answer

I was actually confused with capacity and size. There is no implementation of using a default capacity MutableList currently in Kotlin stdlib.

You can make one yourself.

```kotlin
fun <T> mutableListWithCapacity(capacity: Int): MutableList<T> =
    ArrayList(capacity)

// creates a MutableList of Int with capacity of 5.
val mutableList = mutableListWithCapacity<Int>(5)
```

### Outdated Answer

One of the reason why [mutableListOf](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/mutable-list-of.html) does not allow for default capacity is because default values in kotlin is not null.

However there is a utility function **defined** in `kotlin.collections` package.

```kotlin
public inline fun <T> MutableList(size: Int, init: (index: Int) -> T): MutableList<T> {
    val list = ArrayList<T>(size)
    repeat(size) { index -> list.add(init(index)) }
    return list
}
```

You can create a List with a [List](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list.html) function or [MutableList](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list.html) function with a default capacity and its mapping.

```kotlin
// creates a list of ints with default capacity of 10 and having nulls.
// But I highly doubt you should initialize it with a null since Kotlin is a null-safe language.
val list = MutableList<Int?>(10) { null }
```

But since there should not be nulls in Kotlin if it is intended use of non-null list else you have to do a null check using operators like `?.` `!!.`.

Comment: This answer seems to confuse capacity and length. `MutableList<Int?>(10) { null }` creates a list of _length_ 10, and it's perfectly possible to have a `MutableList<Int>` of length 3 and capacity 10; it doesn't contain nulls.

Answer (score 9):

Fill an immutable list

```
val doubles = List(5) { i -> i * 2 }
result --> [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Fill a mutable list of five elements with zeros

```
val ints = MutableList(5) { 0 }
result --> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: This does not answer the question the questioner asked.

Comment: But still, it has the most upvotes - Don't you think it says something?? Whatever...

Comment: @Barakuda I think it says that people don't understand the difference between capacity and size. But that doesn't make it a correct answer for _this question_

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap this `mutableList()` predefined function in a function like the following

```kotlin
fun <E> emptyMutableList(size: Int = 0): MutableList<E?> {
    return MutableList(size) {
        null
    }
}
```

this will return a `MutableList` of size `size` but also with `null` assigned to all of its cells. Now if you want to access any index value, your program will not crash with `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` like it would if you use the solution in the accepted answer. Here is what I mean:

```kotlin
fun <E> emptyMutableList(size: Int = 0): MutableList<E?> {
    return MutableList(size) {
        null
    }
}

fun <T> mutableListWithCapacity(capacity: Int): MutableList<T> =
    ArrayList(capacity)

fun main() {
    val mutableList1 = mutableListWithCapacity<Int>(20)
    val mutableList2 = emptyMutableList<Int>(20)
    
    mutableList1[10] // this will throw a java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    
    mutableList2[10] // this will not throw an exception but it will return null
}
```

Of course everything depends on how memory efficient vs crash-free you want your program to be.

Happy coding!

Comment: The reason for providing an initial size is to avoid making unnecessary allocations, it's an optimization, by providing an initial value to the list  you are iterating through the list when its created. This counteracts the gains made in providing an initial capacity. May as well just use mutableListOf at that point and reduce code complexity.

Comment: I disagree with ensuring that a list can't throw an IndexOutOfBounds exception, you are essentially obfuscating bugs in your code by doing this. Also shouldn't
`val mutableList2 = emptyMutableList<Int>(20)` be `val mutableList2 = emptyMutableList<Int?>(20)`