# What is the simplest way to pre-size or pre-allocate a MutableList in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Is there a way to initialize a MutableList to a known size? I know how many elements it will ever contain and I could make a for loop to "add" null elements until whatever size is met but in the init or constructor but this seems messy.

What is the simplest way to pre-size or pre-allocate a MutableList in kotlin to a known size? Must I loop and call add(null) over and over?

Comment: [ArrayList](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-list/) is implementation of MutableList and it is what reurned from the mutableListOf() as well. So you can make something like this: `fun <T> mutableListWith(capacity: Int): MutableList<T> = ArrayList(Capacity)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin MutableList initial capacity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61698098/kotlin-mutablelist-initial-capacity)

Comment: I don't think I'd create a function to obscure the ArrayList constructor. Setting an initial capacity is an optimization technique that has nothing to do with the MutableList interface. It's appropriate if optimizing to use the concrete class at the call site, possibly with a comment like `// known minimum size`, and then assign it to a `MutableList` variable if the constructor is the only `ArrayList`-specific feature you're using.