# Pre-initialize size of List/Collection/etc

Tags: kotlin, generics

In languages like C# or Go, you can specify an underlying array's size, so that the runtime does not have to guess. Which can yield some performance benefit (less Garbage collection and copying of array contents).

For example in C#:

```
var listOfCookies = new List<Cookie>(50);
```

In Golang:

```
cookieSlice := make([]cookie, 0, 50)
```

What is the equivalent in Kotlin? Or does it use another approach to allocation of underlying array?

Thanks,
Kotlin Newbie

**Update:**
I found this paragraph in the docs particularly confusing, or does this only apply to Kotlin transpiled to JS?
[image]

Comment: I don't know much about Kotlin, but I thought it used the Java collections, at least for some things - `ArrayList` has a constructor accepting an initial capacity, so I'd expect you to be able to use that in Kotlin.

Comment: Thank you Jon, this makes sense to me. I updated the question, as to why I have some confusion.

Comment: If you scroll up to the top of the page, you'll see 4 buttons - "Common", "JVM", "JS" and "Native". They are actually checkboxes that you can "uncheck". You can uncheck everything that you are not interested in and related documentation won't be displayed. If you uncheck JS, that paragraph will be gone, so yes, it is talking about JS.

Comment: Yes, it only applies to JS (might be worth reporting as an issue at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/ because it could be made clearer e.g. by marking implementation-specific paragraphs).

Comment: And if you look at the details of the class, you'll see that there's a constructor accepting an initial size.

Comment: Thanks for Clarification guys. I have created a ticket in youtrack for a clearer explanation as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61698098/kotlin-mutablelist-initial-capacity